# How to force Instagram to open a link in Safari rather than the in app browser

Tags: javascript, html, safari, instagram

Instagram has added an inapp browser that automatically is used when links are opened. My websites need to be opened in a normal browser such as Safari (for iPhone). I am trying to figure out how to force it to redirect to a proper browser.
If this link is opened through Instagram browser, it will request to be opened in safari, And I am trying to do this:
http://ogurl.co/BOJ

Comment: are you talking about the Instragram app for your phone? Do you mean when you click a link in the phone app you want it to open in a regular browser (safari,chrome,etc)not an in-app one?

Comment: Do you have access to any code or are you looking for a phone setting that makes this happen?

Comment: @rjustin Exactly this!

Comment: Please see answer posted. If it is complete enough for you please accept otherwise ask for clarification, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a specific URL in a specific browser from a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511891/how-to-open-a-specific-url-in-a-specific-browser-from-a-link)

Comment: is there any updated 2022 solution for this?

Comment: It's 2023, and AllMyLinks can do this. I'm still trying to figure how they could do that

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, the in app browser for Instagram or any app is a design decision made by the producer of the application and cannot be changed by the user unless configuration is provided.

If Instagram provides a setting to open the links in a different browser, that would be the only way to make this happen.

Comment: Sorry this isnt what I am looking for. If you look at the link I provided, and set it as lets say your link in your profile on instagram. Then once you click it, it will request to open safari

Comment: @MaximUmansky also heres another Q validating this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511891/how-to-open-a-specific-url-in-a-specific-browser-from-a-link