# Unable to Open and Close Popup window in JavaScript when viewed in Android Frames

Tags: javascript

I open a new tab to show the user some info using:

```
window.open("/Home/Agreement", "_blank");
```

Inside the Agreement View, I put a button with this JavaScript to close the Popup and return to the main tab:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="window.close();">
     return to home
</button>
```

This method works well in Desktop and also when viewed through a standalone browser in Mobile, but when users **navigate to the main page through embedded Web View in Instagram**:

They **cannot close the popup tab** using the button. The button does nothing... and when they press back on their mobile phone, the main page is refreshed, and form input is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,
I fixed it by detecting if the page is open in Instagram agent and redirected it to an external browser with the help of this question on SO:

[Open link in External Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69767955/4805219)