# How to open browser choice in mobile on link click from browser?

Tags: javascript, android-intent, web, mobile, hyperlink

I need to give choices to the user which browser they want to choose to open in **mobile** when he clicks on the link in some browser.

For example, if a user opens my webpage in opera mobile browser, then on that page I have to give a link that will give user choice to open that link in another browser.
My webpage is using simple HTML and javascript.

[This](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)  talks about opening your app from a web browser.

Eg: If we open a link from WhatsApp, it gives choices of browsers, or opens in the default browser.

Comment: You can't decide which browser a given link should be opened with, it is up to the user which one they made the default.

Comment: Yes, u r right. But I want to give choices if no default is set, otherwise open link in default browser.

Comment: As I said, you can't.

Comment: Let say I am opening my webpage in opera and my default browser is chrome. Then I want to open link in chrome(default browser).

Comment: Again, you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a specific URL in a specific browser from a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511891/how-to-open-a-specific-url-in-a-specific-browser-from-a-link)

Comment: It is not duplicate of above question

Comment: No, not the question, but its answer is, and therefore also is being called a _possible duplicate_.

Answer (score -2):

in which linking with browser to set the formation they allow to link with browser 
window.open("https://domain_name","_blank","toolbar=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400"); or
window.open("https://domain_name");

Comment: This only opens link in a new window