# Use browseURL function within RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to add a link to my RMarkdown document (using a flexdashboard), and am aware of the `[Website Name](URL)` method, however in my particular case, the webpage can only be opened in Internet Explorer, and so I want to override my default browser, Chrome.

I have been playing in the console, and have had success with the `browseURL` function, which allows me to specify a file path for the browser to use: `browseURL("http://URL", browser = "c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe")`

My question is, how do I use this function within RMarkdown. I'd like a hyperlink to show up in my rmarkdown HTML page, where the link says "Website Name" and when you click the link, it executes the `browseURL` function and automatically opens Internet Explorer.

I haven't been able to figure out how to get a link to show up in my rmarkdown output that executes `browseURL`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511891/how-to-open-a-specific-url-in-a-specific-browser-from-a-link. Simplest way seems to be asking your users to open the app in Explorer in the first place.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure that will work. Yeah ironically, RMarkdown doesn't render correctly in IE, so I'm forcing my users to open the flexdashboard in Chrome or Firefox. But the link is actually to an InfoPath document, which IE seems to be the only browser to handle opening that document correctly. A weird situation for sure